# I want to find and replace using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to find and replace using jquery, my code is like this:

```
<input id="find" style="width:100%; height:100%;" value="timesSome|standunder|ningmea|uoy|nitiondefi" />
<input id="replace" style="width:100%; height:100%;" value="Sometimes|understand|meaning|you|definition" />
<textarea id="input" style="width:150px; height:100px; resize:none;" wrap="off">timesSome to standunder a word's ningmea uoy need more than a nitiondefi.</textarea>
<textarea id="output" style="width:150px; height:100px; resize:none;" wrap="off"></textarea>
    <button>Process!</button>
```

> **Find:** timesSome|standunder|ningmea|uoy|nitiondefi
>
> **Replace with:** Sometimes|understand|meaning|you|definition
>
> **Input Text:** timesSome to standunder a word's ningmea uoy need more than a nitiondefi.
>
> **Result:** Sometimes to understand a word's meaning you need more than a definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this code. It will help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/madhanminho/17no986h/2/

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#repl").click(function(){
        var data = $('#find').val();
        var data2 = $('#replace').val();
        var arr = data.split('|');
        var arr2 = data2.split('|');
        var res=$("#input").val();
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            res=res.replace(arr[i], arr2[i]);
        }
            $("#output").val(res);


    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="find" style="width:100%; height:100%;" value="timesSome|standunder|ningmea|uoy|nitiondefi" />
<input id="replace" style="width:100%; height:100%;" value="Sometimes|understand|meaning|you|definition" />
<textarea id="input" style="width:150px; height:100px; resize:none;" wrap="off">timesSome to standunder a word's ningmea uoy need more than a nitiondefi.</textarea>
<button id="repl">Process!</button>
<textarea id="output" style="width:150px; height:100px; resize:none;" wrap="off"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking string replace?

```
var inputTextarea = document.getElementById('input');
inputTextarea.value = inputTextarea .value.replace(/timesSome/gi,'sometimes');
```

using g it's case sensitive.
using gi its case insensitive.

There are legions of options possible. Look at javascript regex for the more fun stuff

Answer (score 0):

I have made this function to help you solve the problem, take a look at tha t and try.

```
var tofind = ($("#find").val()).split("|");
var splitInput = ($("#input").text()).split(" ");
var newString=" ";
for(var i=0;i<tofind.length;i++)
{
  for(var j=0;j<splitInput.length;j++)
  {
    if(tofind[i]==splitInput[j])
    {
    if(splitInput[j].length%2 == 0)
        to_add = splitInput[j].substring(splitInput[j].length/2 + 1, splitInput[j].length)+splitInput[j].substring(0,splitInput[j].length/2 + 1);
    else
        to_add = splitInput[j].substring(splitInput[j].length/2, splitInput[j].length)+splitInput[j].substring(0,splitInput[j].length/2);
    newString=newString+to_add+" ";
    }
    else 
    {
        newSTring=newString+splitInput[i]+" ";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @Brijesh Bhatt it says missing ] in index expression.